# Custom error handling globally in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp.net web api.

```
[Route("api/employee")]
[HttpPost]
public dynamic GetData(EmployeeModel model)
{
     EmployeeService emp = new EmployeeService();
     emp.GetData(model);
}
```

This is how I am handling error globally:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
          //Code to log the exception goes here:
    }
 }
```

in the WebApiConfig.cs file, I am registering the filter:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
               ....
               config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
        } 
    }
```

Whenever there is an exception, the exception filter is able to catch the exception & It can log the exception. All this is working fine.

**What I want:** With every exception, I want to log specific details, those details are available in respective methods but how do I pass them to exception filter? The only work around I see is, add try catch block in individual methods and log the exception along with specific details.

Another thing that I want to capture is the request object of each request. In this case it will be ExployeeModel. Even if I somehow get the request object, how to I type cast into correct type. One endpoint can expect EmployeeModel other can expect DepartmentModel.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to pass that's not in the context?

Comment: @Jasen: When I receive input (in this case EmployeeModel), I perform some calculation, lets say tax calculation for the employee & this happens in multiple steps. The error can occur at any step, when that happen, I want to log the current state & few other info.